# How to show long Arabic text in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, text, arabic

In the code below, when small Arabic texts are placed, everything is displayed well, but when the text is long, the letters are displayed separately.

```
Text("مرحبا هذا نص طويل ولكنه باللغة العربية فكيف يمكن عرضه بشكل صحيح")
            .font(.system(size: 16))
            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
          }
```

At first I thought it was happening because of one of the characters, but then I realized it was happening because of the length of the text

[image: Text]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please ignore the bot. This question is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a long-standing bug in Core Text, which SwiftUI is likely using behind the scenes. See [CoreText With Too Long Arabic Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65293503/coretext-with-too-long-arabic-text) for this in a Core Text context. I do not believe this is solvable inside of SwiftUI. You need to create your own UIView (via UIViewRepresentable) and lay this out directly with a CTFramesetter. I'd check if it happens to be right around 10k of text. That's what we found in Core Text, and I expect it is the same in SwiftUI.

Comment: I am new to swif. I used to program with Java and I know concepts like inheritance very well, but I don't know how to "lay this out directly with a CTFramesetter". please explain this to me or give me an article about this. thanks

Comment: See the linked question for an example. The docs and introduction are here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533  I wish I could say there were an gentle introduction, but there isn't really. It's pretty low-level and does have a learning curve to understand it. I don't ususally mention my book because it's so old, but chapter 21 goes into depth on this and hasn't changed much: https://www.amazon.com/iOS-Programming-Pushing-Limits-Applications-ebook/dp/B00HSIJ9YA?

Comment: You can find sample code that might help you get started here, though it's in ObjC and Core Foundation. The Swift will actually be pretty similar, since Swift calls Core Foundation very similarly to how ObjC does. Remember, this is all UIKit. You still have to wrap it up with a UIViewRepresentable to embed it in SwiftUI. It's completely learnable stuff; you can do it. But it's not simple. https://github.com/iosptl/ios7ptl/blob/master/ch21-Text/SimpleLayout/CoreTextLabel.m